# Захват цены, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Я делаю плагин акций. Суть: в админке создаем акцию, указываем разные настройки и скидку. При формировании товаров, делается запрос к БД и у тех товаров, которые включены в акцию, цена домножается на % скидки.

```
  foreach($products_id as $goods_id){      
  $price = $product->get_price($post_id);      
  echo '<span class="price"><span class="amount">'.$price.'</span>';            
  for($i=0; $i<count($products_id); $i++){
    if(in_array($post_id, $products_id[$i])){          
      $new_price = $price-($price*$discount);
      echo '<span class="discount_price">'.$new_price.'</span></span>';                           
    }       
  }      
  break;
}
```

Проблема в том, что цена для корзины/оформления заказов и т.д. не меняется. Я использовал

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'camp_woocommerce_get_price', 10, 2);
```

но у меня ничего не получалось. Каким хуком зацепить это добро?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте хук `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {        
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $discount = get_post_meta( $value['product_id'], 'название поля со скидкой', true ); // Здесь скидка
        $value['data']->price -= ($value['data']->price/100) * $discount;
    }
}
```